# nginx listening on ipv6, but for some reason websites won't load

Tags: nginx, ipv6

I'm trying to get ipv6 working on nginx (nginx/1.19.6) for SSL. In my domain configs I have:

```
server {
    listen      93.93.135.169:443 http2;
    listen      [::]:443 http2;
    server_name backups.myserver.com;
   ....
}
```

..and then for the standard port;

```
server {
    listen      93.93.135.169:80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name backups.myserver.com ;
    ...
}
```

Netstat shows nginx as listening on port 443 and 80:

```
 netstat -tulpn | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 93.93.135.169:80        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1168/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8084          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1168/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 93.93.135.169:443       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1168/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9183            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5247/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1168/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1168/nginx: master
```

I can find the server find on ipv4 and ipv6:

```
root@admin3:~# ping -4 backups.myserver.com
PING backups.myserver.com (93.93.135.169) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from backups.myserver.com (93.93.135.169): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=1.58 ms
^X^C
--- backups.myserver.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.575/1.575/1.575/0.000 ms
root@admin3:~# ping -6 backups.myserver.com
PING backups.myserver.com(2a00:1098:80:a0::1 (2a00:1098:80:a0::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1098:80:a0::1 (2a00:1098:80:a0::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=1.55 ms
^X64 bytes from 2a00:1098:80:a0::1 (2a00:1098:80:a0::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=1.74 ms
```

On **iptables**, I get:

```
iptables --list -n | grep 443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443

iptables --list -n | grep 80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
```

..and ip6tables:

```
ip6tables --list -n | grep 80
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW tcp dpt:80

ip6tables --list -n | grep 443
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW tcp dpt:443
```

Yet , when I test the site on https://ipv6-test.com/ with **http**, it works:

[image]

But as soon as I try SSL, I get:

[image]

Running a curl test from another server to it, I get:

```
curl -v -6 https://backups.myserver.com
*   Trying 2a00:1098:80:a0::1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to backups.myserver.com (2a00:1098:80:a0::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

I'm running out of other things to try. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to tell nginx that these listening ports on port 443 are for TLS.

```
    listen      93.93.135.169:443 http2;
    listen      [::]:443 http2;
```

Note that `ssl` is missing. It should read:

```
    listen      93.93.135.169:443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
```

Comment: OMG I knew I had to be missing something. Duh! Thanks for bringing some sanity to me. It sometimes just takes a fresh pair of eyes to look at something!